# Linear congruential method for Pseudorandom number generator

Tags: java

```
public class Random {
    private static int A=25173;
    private static int C=13849;
    private static int M=65536; 
    public static int next(){
        int z = 23311;
        z=(A*z+C)%M;
    return z;
   }
}
```

How do i refer to the previous number (z_i-1) so that i can keep generating new random numbers when the method is called?

Answer (score 1):

With a `private static int` if you want your class to be `static` (only a wrapper for methods, not the best design!), or a `private int` if youre `Random`-class should be instantiated. In your `next()`-function you can then just write to your new field:

```
public class Random {
    ...
    private static int last = 23311;
    ...
    public static int next(){
        last=(A*last+C)%M;
        return last;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks works great. I understand the difference now.

Comment: @user3514716 You're welcome, consider accepting the answer if you're question is answered to mark the question as answered (under the voting buttons)